# How to use espeak_EVENT_TYPE;

Tags: c++, events, compiler-errors, espeak

I am looking a way to know when `espeak` ended it's speaking. Somebody told use the `espeakEVENT_MSG_TERMINATED`. But when I try to put this part to my code it gives me this error:

```
#include <espeak/speak_lib.h>

espeak_EVENT_TYPE;

    if( espeak_EVENT_TYPE == espeakEVENT_MSG_TERMINATED)
    {
    do something;
    }
```

> application.cpp:31:1: error: declaration does not declare anything
>   [-fpermissive]  espeak_EVENT_TYPE;  ^ application.cpp: In function
>   ‘void speech(char*)’: application.cpp:116:27: error: expected
>   primary-expression before ‘==’ token
>        if( espeak_EVENT_TYPE == espeakEVENT_MSG_TERMINATED)

EDIT: I use this simple code to use `espeak`:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <espeak/speak_lib.h>


espeak_POSITION_TYPE position_type;
espeak_AUDIO_OUTPUT output;
char *path=NULL;
int Buflength = 1000, Options=0;
void* user_data;
t_espeak_callback *SynthCallback;
espeak_PARAMETER Parm;



char Voice[] = {"English"};


char text[30] = {"this is an english text"};
unsigned int Size,position=0, end_position=0, flags=espeakCHARS_AUTO, *unique_identifier;




int main(int argc, char* argv[] ) 
{
    output = AUDIO_OUTPUT_PLAYBACK;
    espeak_Initialize(output, Buflength, path, AUDIO_OUTPUT_SYNCHRONOUS ); //Options ); 
    espeak_SetVoiceByName(Voice);
    const char *langNativeString = "en";
    espeak_VOICE voice = {0};
  //  memset(&voice, 0, sizeof(espeak_VOICE));
        voice.languages = langNativeString;
        voice.name = "US";
        voice.variant = 2;
        voice.gender = 1;
        espeak_SetVoiceByProperties(&voice);
    Size = strlen(text)+1;    

    espeak_Synth( text, Size, position, position_type, end_position, flags,unique_identifier, user_data );
    espeak_Synchronize( );

    return 0;
}
```

Edit2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include <sphinxbase/err.h>
#include <sphinxbase/ad.h>

#include <espeak/speak_lib.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "pocketsphinx.h"
static ps_decoder_t *ps;
static cmd_ln_t *config;
static FILE *rawfd;

ad_rec_t *ad;

espeak_POSITION_TYPE position_type;
espeak_AUDIO_OUTPUT output;
char *path=NULL;
int Buflength = 1000, Options=0;
void* user_data;
char Voice[] = {"English"};
unsigned int Size,position=0, end_position=0, flags=espeakCHARS_AUTO, *unique_identifier;
t_espeak_callback *SynthCallback;
espeak_PARAMETER Parm;

static void initFuncs()
{

    output = AUDIO_OUTPUT_PLAYBACK;
    espeak_Initialize(output, Buflength, path, AUDIO_OUTPUT_SYNCHRONOUS ); 
    espeak_SetVoiceByName(Voice);
    const char *langNativeString = "en";
    espeak_VOICE voice;
    memset(&voice, 0, sizeof(espeak_VOICE));
        voice.languages = langNativeString;
        voice.name = "US";
        voice.variant = 2;
        voice.gender = 1;
        espeak_SetVoiceByProperties(&voice);

}

int receive_espeak_events(short *wav, int numsamples, espeak_EVENT *event)
{
    while (event->type != espeakEVENT_LIST_TERMINATED) {
        if (event->type == espeakEVENT_MSG_TERMINATED) {
            /* do something */
            ad_start_rec(ad);
        }
        ++event; // Examine the next event.
    }
    return 0; // Continue speaking.
}

static void sleep_msec(int32 ms)
{
    struct timeval tmo;

    tmo.tv_sec = 0;
    tmo.tv_usec = ms * 1000;

    select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &tmo);

}

static void speech(char* hyp)
{      
    Size = strlen(hyp)+1;
    espeak_SetSynthCallback(receive_espeak_events);
    espeak_Synth( hyp, Size, position, position_type, end_position, flags,unique_identifier, user_data );
    espeak_Synchronize( );    
}


static void recognize_from_microphone()
{

    ad_rec_t *ad;
    int16 adbuf[2048];
    uint8 utt_started, in_speech;
    int32 k;
    char  *hyp=0;

    if ((ad = ad_open_dev(cmd_ln_str_r(config, "-adcdev"),(int) cmd_ln_float32_r(config,"-samprate"))) == NULL)
        E_FATAL("Failed to open audio device\n");
    if (ad_start_rec(ad) < 0)
        E_FATAL("Failed to start recording\n");

    if (ps_start_utt(ps) < 0)
        E_FATAL("Failed to start utterance\n");


    utt_started = FALSE;
    E_INFO("Ready....\n");

    for (;;) 
    {

        if ((k = ad_read(ad, adbuf, 2048)) < 0)
            E_FATAL("Failed to read audio\n");
        ps_process_raw(ps, adbuf, k, FALSE, FALSE);
        in_speech = ps_get_in_speech(ps);
        if (in_speech && !utt_started) 
        {
            utt_started = TRUE;
            E_INFO("Listening...\n");
        }
        if (!in_speech && utt_started) 
        {

            ps_end_utt(ps);
            hyp = (char*)ps_get_hyp(ps, NULL );
            if (hyp != NULL) 
            {
///////////////////I am passing hyp to espeak heere ////////////////////
             ad_stop_rec(ad);
             speech(hyp);

                printf("%s\n",hyp);
                fflush(stdout);
            //    sleep_msec(3000);

            }

            if (ps_start_utt(ps) < 0)
                E_FATAL("Failed to start utterance\n");
            utt_started = FALSE;
            E_INFO("Ready....\n");

        }
    }//for
    ad_close(ad);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    initFuncs();

                 config = cmd_ln_init(NULL, ps_args(), TRUE,
                 "-hmm", "/home/m/myrobot3/robot/model_parameters/robot.cd_cont_1000",
                     "-lm","/home/m/myrobot3/robot/etc/robot.lm.bin",
                     "-dict", "/home/m/myrobot3/robot/etc/robot.dic",
                     NULL);

    ps = ps_init(config);
    recognize_from_microphone();

    ps_free(ps);
    cmd_ln_free_r(config);

    return 0;
}
```

ERROR:

> FATAL: "application.cpp", line 163: Failed to read audio

Comment: Have you registered a callback function with `espeak_SetSynthCallback()`?

Comment: @JackC.: No I don't know how can I use it? I updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

```
espeak_EVENT_TYPE;
```

This line is not sensible to the compiler.  `espeak_EVENT_TYPE` is a data type.  It is not a variable that can be compared to a value like `espeakEVENT_MSG_TERMINATED`.  In order to declare a variable, the syntax would be:

```
espeak_EVENT_TYPE an_event_type {};
if (an_event_type == espeakEVENT_MSG_TERMINATED) {
/* ... */
```

However, if we do this, then the variable `an_event_type` that we just created will not actually contain any information about any real espeak event.  And it certainly won't say anything about whether any actual message is terminated or not.

### Receiving real event information from espeak

In order to get information about whether a message is terminated, the program needs to obtain a variable of type `espeak_EVENT_TYPE` from the espeak library.

Looking through [this header](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/speak_lib.h), `espeak_EVENT_TYPE` is used as part of the `espeak_EVENT` struct.  To receive `espeak_EVENT` notifications, it is necessary to write a function which will be called by the espeak library.  (This is known as a "callback" function).  Then the callback function is registered with the library by calling `espeak_SetSynthCallback`.

From the same header, the prototype of the callback function must be as follows:

> int SynthCallback(short *wav, int numsamples, espeak_EVENT *events);
>
> wav:  is the speech sound data which has been produced. NULL 
>           indicates that the synthesis has been completed.
>
> numsamples: is the number of entries in wav.  This number may vary, 
>   may be less than the value implied by the buflength parameter given in > espeak_Initialize, and may sometimes be zero (which does NOT indicate
>   end of synthesis).
>
> events: an array of espeak_EVENT items which indicate word and
>   sentence events, and also the occurance if  and  elements
>   within the text.  The list of events is terminated by an event of type > = 0.
>
> Callback returns: 0=continue synthesis,  1=abort synthesis.

Putting this together, we need a function that loops through the `events` variable as if it is an array, until it encounters an event of type 0.  Then the function needs to return 0 to continue speech activities.

```
int receive_espeak_events(short *wav, int numsamples, espeak_EVENT *event)
{
    while (event->type != espeakEVENT_LIST_TERMINATED) {
        if (event->type == espeakEVENT_MSG_TERMINATED) {
            /* do something */
        }
        ++event; // Examine the next event.
    }
    return 0; // Continue speaking.
}
```

To tell espeak to call this function, pass the function to `espeak_SetSynthCallback` before starting any synthesis operations.

```
espeak_SetSynthCallback(receive_espeak_events);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jack! I tried your code and put my complete code and updated my question, but still gives me error. I don't know if you know `pocketsphinx` or not, but the important part is that, I get the recognized text from the user speech and collect it inside `char* hyp` and try to pass it through `espeak` to say what tha text is collected inside `hyp`. Also you can see this question to exactly find what I wanted to do? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50062009/how-to-find-if-espeak-ended-the-speech?noredirect=1#comment87168322_50062009

Comment: I tested your code, but I think there is a problem. The sequence of my interesting things is like this : 1.pocketsphinx recognizes a word and stores it within `hyp`. 2.I pass the `hyp` to `espeak` by `speech()` function. 3. `espeak` reads the `hyp` and the rest of the code after `speech()` function is on pause. But when I must call `espeak_SetSynthCallback()` before the `espeak_Synth` I can not reach my purpose in step 3, and the program will not be paused till espeak ends speaking!

Comment: `espeak_SetSynthCallback()` should probably be called once after `espeak_Initialize` in `initFuncs`.  There is no need to call `espeak_SetSynthCallback` for each time through `espeak_Synth`.  Also, if all you want to do is wait for synthesis to complete, `espeak_Synchronize` should already be doing that for you.

Comment: I tried to put `espeak_SetSynthCallback()` inside the `initFuncs()` and remove it from `speech()` but result is the same error!

Comment: You know, the `pocketsphinx` is a real-time app, it uses `ad_rec_start(ad);` to start the listening to microphone, then recognizes the voices and stores what it recognizes within the `hyp` variable. But when I try to pass the `hyp` to `espeak` to say what it recognized, `pocketsphinx` is still listening and it's causes an ultimate repeating the first word it recognized, because it listens to what `espeak` says after the first recognized voice from the user.

Comment: So I must use `ad_rec_stop(ad);` function to stop the `pocketsphinx's` listening untill the espeak ends the espeaking, to avoid the above problem!  But I don't know how to do it and my app crashes :(